# Change directory in a server without leaving the working directory

Tags: python, sockets, directory, cd

I have a server. Client can send a path and server should `cd` to that path. But here is the thing. Imagine I have a `test2` directory in `test1` directory and the path to `test1` directory is `C:\test1`. The client can access `test2` by `cd test2` and `\test1\test2` and if he wants to go back he can use `\test1` (I searched and found `os.chdir` but it needs the full path and I don't have it) and he shouldn't be free to send `E:\something` or anything like that. Just the directories that are in `test1`. what do you suggest? what can I use to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store the default path as a kind of root path and path.join(root, client_path) this way you have a complete path that has to start with C:\test1

The issue you have to overcome is deciding if you have to join the current path or the root path with the client's command. I would first check if the directory exists in the current working directory if not I would try finding it in the "root" path

Comment: If you root is C:\test1 and you send "test2\test3\test4" it will send you to  "test1/test2/test3/test4", if you send now "test2" it will join root (C:\test1) and "test2". The issue you have to overcome is deciding if you have to join the current path or the root path with the client's command. I would first check if the directory exists in the current working directory if not I would try finding it in the "root" path.

Comment: ""The issue you have to overcome is deciding if you have to join the current path or the root path with the client's command. I would first check if the directory exists in the current working directory if not I would try finding it in the "root" path""  is my answer thank you

Comment: please add this part to your answer for others